# Create correct Criteria Operator

Tags: devexpress, criteria, xpo

Trying to create a Criteria.Parse operator when I have to convert the string field to an Int.
Operation fails at the follwing:

> Message=Parser error at line 0, character 15: syntax error;
> ("Convert.ToInt16{FAILED HERE}(awayML)>130")

Here is my code:

```
XPCollection collection = new XPCollection(session1, typeof(TodaysGame), CriteriaOperator.Parse("Convert.ToInt16(awayML)>130"));
int ct = collection.Count;
```

How do I form the Criteria using the Convert.ToInt16 function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Criteria operators have their own syntax to convert string literals to int values. You need to use them instead of system Convert.ToInt function:

| Function | Description | Example |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ToInt(Value) | Converts Value to an equivalent 32-bit signed integer. | ToInt([Value]) |
| ToLong(Value) | Converts Value to an equivalent 64-bit signed integer. | ToLong([Value]) |

You can check the full reference of DevExpress criteria syntax [here](https://docs.devexpress.com/CoreLibraries/4928/devexpress-data-library/criteria-language-syntax)

Comment: Nikita, I checked the DevExpress reference and changed my code to the following:  "    XPCollection<TodaysGame> collection = new XPCollection<TodaysGame>(session1, CriteriaOperator.Parse("ToInt[awayML]) >130")); "   and I'm still getting an error "Message=Parser error at line 0, character 13: syntax error; ("ToInt[awayML]{FAILED HERE}) >130")"

Comment: ToInt[(Value]) not available in version 10.1 of DevExpress Library

Answer (score 2):

The correct way to build a Criteria like that would be:

```
CriteriaOperator.Parse("ToInt([awayML]) > 130");
```